# java check the first and last char are uppercase

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am trying to achieve this.
 I have a string of 9char (always the same). But i also know that the first and last char is always a aplhabetic, it must be. the rest in the middle are numbers. How to check for that.
I got this logic so far, syntax is my problem

```
string samplestring;
samplestring = a1234567B
If(samplestring.length() == 9 && samplestring.substring(0,1).uppercase && samplestring.substring(8,9) && samplestring.THE REST OF THE CHAR IN THE MIDDLE ARE DIGITS)

{
 println("yes this is correct");
}

else
{
println("retype");
}
```

Please dont mind about the simple english just want to know the syntax but the logic is there i hope..

Also can please show me those lowercase ones how to convert to uppercase?

Comment: First and last character are upper case? I don't see this being mentioned anywhere apart from the title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regular expression would be suitable:

```
String s = new String("A2345678Z");
if (s.matches("[A-Z][0-9]{7}[A-Z]")))
{
}
```

Regular expression explained:

- `[A-Z]` means any uppercase letter
- `[0-9]{7}` means 7 digits

Comment: You should probably use `\p{javaUpperCase}` instead of `[A-Z]`, since there are many more uppercase letters than A-Z.

Comment: hey can u show me if the string is found to be NOT in uppercase convert them to uppercase..tks

Comment: @JackyBoi, just `s = s.toUpperCase()` if the `matches()` fails and retry (or call it beforehand).

Comment: @hmjd hi i think all the people who replied failed to notice that in my example i mentioned that a1234567B so the first and last characters can be upper or lower case , so is there a regex for that? currently i am using  && operator to do the checking any clever method to solve my problem?

Comment: @JackyBoi, change regex to `"[a-zA-Z][0-9]{7}[a-zA-Z]"`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]\\d+[A-Za-z]$");
Matcher m = p.match("A1234567B");
if (m.matches()) {
  //
}
```

Edit:

If there are always seven digits, you can replace the `\\d+` with `\\d{7}`

Comment: It also mentioned that the string was 9 chars long, so you know there'll be 7 digits in the middle.

Comment: hey can u show me if the string is found to be NOT in uppercase convert them to uppercase..tks

Comment: @JackyBoi I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly, but you can do that by using: myString = myString.toUpperCase().

Comment: @Forlan07 oh its that simple? ok basically reffering to my question, a1234567B, but i want the alphabets to be all UPPERCASE, so u r suggestion still applies?

Comment: @JackyBoi By using toUpperCase() all your characters (a-z) will be uppercase.

Comment: @Forlan07 wat?!! using toLowerCase() all my characters will be uppercase? dopnt u mean toUpperCase()?

Comment: @Forlan07 oh ok..i my programming knoweledge has turned upside down.. once i heard that.. haha tks didn't realize its that simple..

Answer (score -1):

```
String str="A12345678B";
char first = str.charAt(0);
char second = str.charAt(str.length()-1);
if(Character.isUpperCase(first)&& Character.isUpperCase(second)){
    //do something
}
```